# При выполнении скрипта php через консоль выдаёт код html и некорректно отображает кириллицу

Tags: php, cmd

Хочу запустить и выполнить такой скрипт, вот его код из файла:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Пример</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo 'Hello!'; 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

При выполнении его в консоли получаю вот что:

```
C:\Users\Администратор>cd C:\WebServers\home\test1.ru\www
    C:\WebServers\home\test1.ru\www>php index.php
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>╨Я╤А╨╕╨╝╨╡╤А</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Hello!
    </body>
    </html>
```

Почему при выполнении скрипта, мне в консоли выдаёт весь этот html код, а не сам результат "Hello!"

Кодировка стоит UTF-8 (без BOM)

А слово "Пример" в блоке title вообще выдаёт непонятной кодировкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. По той же причине почему и браузер получает html а не только то что вы указали в тегах. Все что в файле это "результат выполнения скрипта".
2. Консоль windows, по умолчанию, не понимает UTF-8. Один из вариантов решения описан [здесь](http://osdir.com/ml/lib.icu.c++.support/2005-01/msg00043.html):

   - открыть терминал
   - в свойствах окна (правой кнопкой на заголовке, пункт свойства), на вкладке шрифт, заменить на Lucida Console
   - выполнить команду `chcp 65001`

В любом случае проблемы с русскими символами останутся, могут не все корректно отображать, по этому или пишите для консольных команд все на английском, или используйте виртуальную машину для сервера и терминал из юникс системы, или поставьте другой терминал.

Answer (score 1):

Надо убрать из файла весь html код.
Оставить только

```
<?php
echo 'Hello!'; 
?>
```