# Русские символы readline() CLI PHP

Tags: php, windows, php7, консоль

Запрашиваю ввод в командной строке, в PHP (v.7.1.2) CLI SAPI, с помощью функции `readline()`, но в командной строке, при вводе русских символов, каракули, и иэроглифы.

Пример кода:

```
$data = readline("Введите Сообщение: ");
```

Знаю, можно поменять функцию запроса данных, на `fgest`, но надо разобраться с `readline`.

Comment: Эта функция использует внешнюю библиотеку. Следовательно в условии задачи не хватает операционки и настроек окружения, в котором запускаете скрипт.

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос следующей информацией - OS (если это не WinNT, то вывод команды locale), версия PHP, пример кода

Comment: Я понял, использую windows, PHP последняя версия. А пример кода не требуется, просто запрос ввода данных. Можно по подробнее с локалью?

Comment: Не про [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572948/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-php-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-html-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5/572956#572956) ли речь ?

Comment: К сожалению, нет.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов пхп последней версии, какой из веток? Вы уточняйте нормально. Пример кода, для людей которые скопипастят его и вставят, а не лезть смотреть доку, писать пример, тестить.

Comment: У меня в винде, версия 5.6, такой функции нет, как указано в первом комментарии http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readline.php

Comment: @Bookin тут автор ответил на ваши вопросы (смотрите в содержимое вопроса)

Comment: @NickVolynkin к чему это и о чем?

Comment: @Bookin вы просили автора добавить пример кода и версию пхп. Он добавил, но вас не уведомил через `@`. Делаю это за него.

Comment: @NickVolynkin боюсь просил не я а "Борис"

Comment: @Bookin а вот же комментарий: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719074/%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-readline-cli-php?noredirect=1#comment1082295_719074

Comment: @NickVolynkin странно, увидел только после вашей ссылки, ну ладно, извиняюсь.